# Understanding syntax puzzle in c

Tags: c, syntax, printf

In an upcoming exam in c, we have one question that gives you extra credit.

The question is always related to tricky syntax of various printing types.

Overall, I understood all the questions I have gone through, but two questions in particular had me puzzled :

What is the output of the following program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    printf ("%c", '&'&'&');
}
```

answer: &

What is the output of the following program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main(){
    printf("%c",strcmp("***","**")*'*');
}
```

answer: *

As you can see the questions are quite similar.
My question is, why is this the output?

Regarding the first question: I understand that a character is, logic-wise, always TRUE and that AND-ing TRUE with TRUE gives you TRUE (or 1) as well, but why would it convert 1 to '&', why not the char equivalent of 1 from the ASCII-table? (notice the required print of %c and not %d)

Regarding the second question: I understand that strcmp returns an int according to the value that 'appears first in the dictionary' and in this example would result in 1 but why multiplying it with the char '*' (again, logic-wise equals to 1) would result in converting (1*1=1) to char '*'?

Comment: `&` is bitwise and, not a boolean operator. The second one is unspecified behaviour because `strcmp` is only specified to return a positive integer, not necessarily 1. And 'char` is an integer, not a boolean.

Comment: Thank you! I now have a much better understanding regarding & and && :)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first question the expression is `'&' & '&'`, where `&` is a *bitwise* AND operator (not a logical operator). With bitwise AND the result of `x & x` is `x`, so the result in this case is just the character `'&'`.

For the second question, assuming the the result of the call to `strcmp()` is `1`, you can then simplify the expression to `1 * '*'` which is just `'*'`. (Note that as [@rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) mentions in the comments above, the result of `strcmp` is not guaranteed to be 1 in this case, only that it will be an integer > 0, so you should not rely on this behaviour, and the question is therefore a bad question).

Answer (score 1):

1. `'&'` is a constant of type `int`. `'&'&'&'` has the same value and type as `'&'` since `a & a` is `a` for any `int` `a`. So the output is equivalent to `printf ("%c", '&');`.
2. The analysis of the second snippet is more difficult. The result of `strcmp` is a positive number. And that is multiplied by `'*'` (which must be a positive number for any *encoding* supported by C). That's an `int` but the value is implementation defined (subject to the encoding on your platform and your platform's implementation of `strcmp`), and the behaviour of `%c` is contingent on the signedness or otherwise of `char` on your platform. If the result is too big to fit into a `char`, and `char` is `unsigned`, then the value is converted to a `char` with the normal wrap-around behaviour. If `char` is `signed` then the conversion is implementation-defined and an implementation-defined signal might be raised.